# Is there datagridview_CellFormating used to format display of Cells in dataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm doing an application to manage students. It loads data from `SQL server` to `DataGridView`. My table has a `Boolean` field, it named as **Gender**. 
When table loaded into `DataGridView`, the column of Gender just displayed under *checkboxes* type. I want to change its the presentative way to another way instead of *checkboxes* like this. (String shows "**Male**" or "**Female**").

[image: Appication Captured]

I've tried on many solutions that are searched on google. But I cannot find out the solving of my problem.

SQL create table code:

```
create table Student
(
    CodeSV varchar(5) not null primary key,
    FirstnameSV varchar(20) not null, 
    LastnameSV varchar(30) not null, 
    BirthDate date,
    Gender bit not null,
)
```

Object properties:

```
public int CodeSV{ get; set; }
public string FirstnameSV { get; set; }
public string LastnameSV { get; set; }
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
public bool Gender { get; set; }
```

I used this code to show data in DataGridView:

```
List<Object> list = new List<Object>();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
list = ObjectDAO.ListAllStudent();
if (list != null)
{
    bs.DataSource = list;
    dgvManager.DataSource = bs;
    dgvManager.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
}
```

Comment: Coding for the present and future: Extend Gender from a binary value to at least three values plus an 'unknown' state..1

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a `Class` for this, then I recommend you modify it to do as you describe. When using a `List<T>` as a `DataSource` to the grid, the “publicly” exposed (non-collection) properties of the class will get mapped to the columns in the grid. In this case the `Gender` field is a Boolean and will display as a check box.

To have this value display as a string value (male/female) … then I suggest you create this “property” in the `Student` Class…. Something like below…

```
public string GenderString {
  get {
    if (Gender) {
      return "Male";
    }
    return "Female";
  }
}
```

This will “add” the GenderString column to the grid. If you do not want the `Gender` “Boolean” column to display, you can either make it invisible in the grid or make the `Gender` property `private.` Bear in mind if you make the `Gender` propert `private`, you will need to make a public “set” method to set its value;

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably are looking for is the `dataGridView_CellPainting` event.

Here you can draw a string with the content you want and use various built-in helper functions to draw the other things the cell should display.

When done set `e.Handled = true;` to prevent the normal painting from overdrawing your stuff.

Example that displays the checkboxes to the left and a text to the right:

[image]

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if ( e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        Brush br = e.State.HasFlag(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) ?
            SystemBrushes.HighlightText : SystemBrushes.WindowText;
        Font font = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font;
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.X + 24, e.CellBounds.Y, 
            e.CellBounds.Width - 24, e.CellBounds.Height);

        e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);

        using (StringFormat fmt = new StringFormat()
        { LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center})
           if (e.Value != null) e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), font, br, r2, fmt);

        e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I'm lazy and use a magic number (`24`) for the offset but there are ways to determine the best value in a more flexible way, if need be..

The cell is aligned like this:

```
dataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```

As DGV checkboxes won't believe in their changes until the user leaves the cell we need this to work as expected:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```

Note: The values produced by `ToString` are here `True` and `False`. If you set your checkbox to allow a 3rd state (`ThreeState = true`) the will be `Checked`, `Unchecked`and `Indeterminate`. It is then up to you to test for these and display a string you want.

As noted in my comment you actually should allow at least one alternate gender **and** an undecided state; so, `CheckBox` is not really the best option. Do consider using a dropdown list instead!